# check if exist before saving document mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to save a document that contains a string that have to be unique in my collection.

This is the model:

```
const invoiceSchema = new Schema({
    date: { type: Date },
    increment: { type: Number },
    nInvonce: { type: String }, // Cant be duplicated in the collection
})
```

"nInvonce" is a string that i create from the last registered document in the collection.

```
// I get the last invoice registered in my collection
    invoiceModel.findOne({}).sort({ '_id': '-1' }).then((invoice)=>{

    var year = new Date(req.body.date)

    req.body.increment= invoice.increment + 1
    req.body.nInvoice = `${year.toString(10)}-` + req.body.increment;

//HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO CHECK ( I GUESS )
    invoiceModel.create(req.body)
})
```

so what i want to do is check if that 'nInvoice' exists in my collection before create the new document. I want to do this because, debuggin my app, i clicked several times in the buttom that send the query and i had duplicated nInvoice...

So what i did is to block the buttom after query is sent... but i am scared that in the future, if diferents users of my app are sending querys to create invoices they get duplicated numbers, how is the best procedure to do it? Any help is apreciated, thanks

Comment: You can add `unique: true` option to your `nInvoice` column in your schema. Be careful though because there's a catch: `unique` is not a validator.
[Read here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator)

Comment: @jstarnate So, it is basically saying that if catch detect that is a duplicated error, i should increment again the number and try save again? am i right?

Comment: If that's your goal, just do the validation and incrementing on route's callback. The schema validators and options just prevent any data that contradict what you want from entering and mutating in the database.